# What are all the illegal characters in the XFS filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, illegal-characters

Could someone provide (or point me to a list) of all the illegal characters in the XFS filesystem? I'm writing an app that needs to sanitize filenames.

EDIT:

Okay, so POSIX filesystems should allow all characters except the NUL character, forward slash, and the '.' and '..' filenames are reserved. All other exceptions are application-level. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the list of legal characters be shorter?

Comment: If you want to sanitize filenames, you may want to remove a number of otherwise legal characters from filenames, such as control characters (unless part of an international filename).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX filesystems (including XFS) allow every character in file names, with the exception of NUL (0x00) and forward-slash (/; 0x2f).

- NUL marks the end of a C-string; so it is not allowed in file names.
- / is the directory separator, so it is not allowed.
- File names starting with a dot (`.`; 0x2e) are considered hidden files. This is a userland, not kernel or filesystem convention.
- There may be conventions you're following — for example, UTF-8 file names — in which case, there are many, many more restrictions including which normalization form to use.

Now, you probably want to disallow other things too; file name with all kinds of weird characters are no fun to deal with. I strongly suggest the whitelist approach.

Also, when handling file names, beware of the `..` entry in every directory. You don't want to traverse it and allow an arbitrary path.

Source: [Single Unix Spec v. 3, §3.169](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_169), "the characters composing the name may be selected from the set of all character values excluding the slash character and the null byte."

Comment: So then disallowing the star character "*" is up to the operating system, then?

Comment: The star character (0x2a) is allowed. Running this should make one; note the backslash to escape from the shell: touch foo\*

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS), any character except NUL is legal in an XFS filesystem file name.  Of course, POSIX typically doesn't allow the forward slash `'/'` in a filename.  Other than this, anything should be good, including international characters.

Comment: Hmm... so far it looks like [/*"?]. Those characters are non-NUL ASCII

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer.  '*' and '?' and '"' should be legal.  Just not NUL and '/'.